# Is there any minimum size requirement for the pinhole in the pinhole camera?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I am trying to build a [Pinhole Camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera) with pinhole size in micrometer range. In my setup I have placed two lights sources with maximum brightness. Still not enough light rays are passing through the pinhole.

Is there any minimum size requirement for the pinhole in the pinhole camera to allow light to pass through?

[image: Experiment Setup]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Look into [Light Portals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/light_settings.html#area-lights).

Comment: Thank you but Light Portals doesn't make much difference. Still not enough light rays are passing through the pinhole to get an image.

Comment: can you please share some screenshot to better understand the problem and your blend file https://blend-exchange.com, maybe the dimensions are too small.

Comment: The pinhole size I want to achieve is in the micrometer range (50μm -100μm). But even with a 3 mm pinhole I can't get a proper image.

Comment: I want to know if there is any minimum size required for the pinhole.

Comment: I don't think there is a technical limit, but I reckon there is definitely a practical one. In path tracing engines, indoor rendering with just an outdoor light going through a hole are particularly harder to render due to how the render process works. You definitely need significantly more rays, and using a portal to guide the rays. But the smaller the hole, the fewer light can go through the hole and you don't have an infinite amount of rays. Either blow up the samples and prepare for ridiculously long renders if it's even enough, or use a bigger hole.

Comment: For reference, a hair strand is between 40 to 100 µm diameter on average. I will check your file once I'm back home and see what can be done.

Comment: Related: the following video basically recreates a camera in Blender Cycles, which starts with a pinhole cam. [Make Your Renders Unnecessarily Complicated - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE9rEQAGpLw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a pinhole camera, you need to have a white material on the "screen" area. A black material would absorb the light rays instead of bouncing them back to you.

You did assign a white diffuse material to the back face of your cube, but you also use a boolean modifier to create the inner volume of the cube. And that boolean operation isn't set up to apply the white material to the inside, so you effectively have no white screen in your box.

To be honest, you don't need to give your cube a thickness. If you really want to, I would replace that first boolean by a Solidify modifier. You can check the presence of your black and white materials using the Material shading mode:

[image]

I also renamed things a bit for clarity.

For ease of use, I highly recommand you to not hide the pinhole object: hidden objects can't be selected and are harder to manipulate. Instead, disable it only its render visibility. Disable all its ray visibilities so that it doesn't impact viewport rendering either, and set its viewport display to wire:

[image]

Now if we try rendering with 3ųm, it works, but it's really noisy. I set this pinhole to 1cm, here's what we see in the viewport after 100 thousand samples:

[image]

In Properties Editor > Render Settings tab > Color Management panel, set the Exposure to 10:

[image]

Still very noisy, and that's normal: Rays are being shot and bouncing everywhere in the scene, only a few make it through the pinhole.

Let's help that by adding an area lamp, enable its Portal option, and place it in the pinhole.

- Select the pinhole object
- Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > Cursor to selected
- Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Add Light > Area
- Rotate it by -90⁰ on X by pressing <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-90</kbd><kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>
- Under Properties Editor > Light Data tab > Light panel, enable Portal and set the size to the same dimension as your pinhole

[image]

It isn't a huge difference because it is still naturally a very noisy image, but it is there.

You can probably tweak things to get better results, use denoising, more samples, change light paths settings, play with different exposures and pinhole sizes, ...

This is the result of one million samples with and without denoising:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it work in the micrometer range? Even after modification I am still not able to get the image in micrometer range.

Comment: Can you also share the blend file?

Comment: It works, but again: the smaller the hole, the less rays get in, the more noisy and dark the image. I don't have the file anymore, but you will get the same result by doing what I described in my answer.